# Python VsCode: Green highlight on class not working

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, highlight

I have the following python code:

```
from typing import List


class User:
    id: str
    name: str

    def __init__(self, id: str, name: str):
        self.id
        self.name = name


UserList = List[User]
```

User is highlighted in green but not UserList.

Here is a screen shot on VsCode:
[image: screen_shot_invalid_highlight]

It causes incoherent highlights such as:
[image: incoherent_highlights]

**Is there a way to have UserList highlighted in green by VsCode ?**

*VsCode Version: 1.65.2 with python and Pylance extension installed*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semantic scope of `UserList` is :`variable.other.readwrite`

The semantic scope of `User` is: `entity.name.type.class`

---

on the line

```python
from typing import List, Tuple
```

`List` and `Tuple` have a different color and scope

This should not be so it validates a bug issue for Pylance