# VsCode - Python: how to have consistent typing highlighting color?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-typing

Here is a simple example of python code:

```
from typing import List, Tuple


class User:
    id: str
    name: str

    def __init__(self, id: str, name: str):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name


UserList = List[User]
UserTuple = Tuple[User, User]

alice = User(id='a', name='Alice')
bob = User(id='b', name='Bob')

user_list: UserList = [alice, bob]
alice_and_bob: UserTuple = (alice, bob)
```

On vsCode, with Python & Pylance extensions, it gives:
[image]

UserTuple does not appear in Green. I understand that it is not an instantiable class (Tuple comes from typing module) while User is. But It makes the code highlight inconsistent: when i type a user, it appears in Green But When I type a UserTuple, it appears in Blue.

**Is there a way to have consistent highlight color for typing in python ?**

*Note:*
*I am the author of a related question: [Python VsCode: Green highlight on class not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71765565/python-vscode-green-highlight-on-class-not-working) But this question is different: List have different highlight color than Tuple in typing module, which apparently is a bug on typing module. But Tuple has correct color, there is no bug on Tuple, it appears in green as expected. The bug comes when i combine two types with valid color (Tuple and User combined to have UserTuple in this example).*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python VsCode: Green highlight on class not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71765565/python-vscode-green-highlight-on-class-not-working)

Comment: I am the author of the link you gave.
No it does not answer: List have different highlight color as Tuple in typing module, which apparently is a bug on typing module. But Tuple has correct color, there is no bug on Tuple, it appears in green as expected. The bug comes when i combine two types with valid color (UserTuple in this example).

Comment: It is the same, the wrong colored words have semantic scope `variable.other.readwrite`, create an issue at PyLance and show both cases